# Synonym [gce] to [google-compute-engine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

[gce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gce) and [google-compute-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine)

It's pretty obvious these are referring to the same thing in nearly all circumstances. GCE is simply an acronym. The longer, and clearer, tag should be made the only remaining tag, especially since there is significant overlap (28 questions have both tags, and 30 have [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) without the longer GCE tag)

Comment: Also, [tag:google-compute-engine] is sponsored. Removing it probably won't be appreciated by the sponsor. Another reason that should be the main tag.

Comment: There is also [GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gke) and [google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-container-engine/info)